# Get the HTML formatting in jQuery TE and display the same formatting in a Div in another HTML Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm Using jQuery TE for Text formatting. I'm Entering some text in the text editor and performing some action like Bold, Italic, Ordered list, header to my text and formatting. Once I finish formatting the text.

I need to click the submit button. After Click the submit button I need to get the same formatting what i entered in the text editor and need to display the content in div in another HTML page with same formatting. Kindly Check the HTML & jQuery below. Thanks in advance..

PAGE 1:

HTML:

```
<textarea name="textarea" id="textArea"></textarea>
<button id="getData">Sumbit</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#textArea').jqte();
$("#getData").click(function() {
    window.htmlString = $( '#textArea' ).html();
    $( '#receiceData' ).html( htmlString );
});
```

PAGE 2 :

HTML:

```
<div id="receiceData"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
First-page(demo.html)

HTML content
<form action = "./demo1.html" method="GET">
    <textarea id = "textArea" name="text"></textarea>
    <button id="getData">Done</button>
</form>

JS content
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('textarea').jqte();
$("#getData").click(function() {
    var htmlString = $( '#textArea' ).val();
    localStorage.setItem("data", htmlString);

});
```

});

```
second page(demo1.html)

HTML content    
<p id="receiceData"></p>

JS content
<script>
     var htmlString =     localStorage.getItem("data");
  $( '#receiceData' ).html(htmlString);
</script>
```

Comment: This is working in same page... I need to pass the same formatting to another HTML Page..

Comment: Hi better u use the local storage concept.